# Dockerfile copy file without version

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In my project, after the build, there are two files

**build/libs**

- backend-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- backend-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar

How can I get rid of the jar version designation when building a docker image

```
COPY --from=builder /home/source/build/libs/backend-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/api/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the file while copying.

```
COPY --from=builder \
    /home/source/build/libs/backend-api-*-SNAPSHOT.jar \
    /home/api/backend.jar
```

Dockers [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) instruction is using  Go’s [filepath.Match rules](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match).

Comment: Thanks but I want copy something like backend-api*.jar The problem is that two files fall under this pattern

Comment: @LeshaRB, why do you need to use such pattern?

Comment: So that when updating the version, do not change the Dockerfile every time .. It will work for both backend-api-0.0.1.jar and backend-api-2.0.0.jar for example

Comment: @LeshaRB thats why you have the star in the middle, but SNAPSHOT is not variable, it will always be there. So the pattern I have used is sufficient for the usecase you just described.